# How to enable Windows 10 Hotspot / Wi-Fi Direct without internet connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, hotspot

Are there any news on that topic?

The latest version of Windows 10 update removed the hosted network functionality that I used before and now I'm forced to use Wi-Fi Direct instead.

I don't want to share an internet connection but set up a WiFi network.

I use the Wi-Fi Direct commands to enable the featuere, set SSID and PW and also disable the timeout through the registry. And I use my own DHCP server for that adapter then.

All that works perfectly fine, there only is one problem: If the computer has no internet connection Windows refuses to enable the Wi-Fi direct feature.

If I enable it while having an internet connection and then remove the internet connection it will stay enabled.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: You can do it programmatically by starting WiiFi Direct Legacy SoftAP.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks for pointing me into that direction. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a P2P or hosted network for this and your wireless network adapters must have P2P support. Open an elevated command prompt and run `netsh wlan show drivers | find /I "Hosted network supported: Yes"`. If it results nothing then you need to update or reinstall wlan drivers. If supported you can continue. Then run `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=yourcustomssid key=password`. Then run `netsh wlan start hostednetowrk`. Now it will start the hosted network and you can connect other devices to it.

Comment: I've already written in my original question that this feature was removed through a Windows (driver) update and ist not available anymore. I used it for this purpose before.

Answer (score 0):

Install your windows 7 driver to windows 10/11 and it will work. You can find your driver files inside a path like that: C:/Windows/System32/DriverStore/FileRepository/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).